# How do I use multiple parameters in jquery ajax function?

Tags: jquery

```
var states = new Array();        
    states[0] = { Id: 1, Name: "Maharashtra" };
    states[1] = { Id: 2, Name: "Punjab" };

    var Id = new Array();
    Id[0] = 0;
    Id[1] = 1;




    $.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        url: "WebService.asmx/MultiDim",
        data: "{'states':" + JSON.stringify(states) +",'rowId':" + JSON.stringify(Id) + "}",
        contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
        dataType: "json",
        success: function (msg) {
            // Do something interesting here.
        }
    });    


[WebMethod]
        public void MultiDim(statesTemplate[] states, Id rowId)
        {

        }
```

I am not getting the rowId second paramter in my webservice function.

Answer (score 0):

Try:

```
data : { states : states, rowId : Id },
```

You can pass the `$.ajax()` function a `data` property that is an object, jQuery will take care of the rest.

> **data**
>
> Data to be sent to the server. **It is converted to a query string, if
>   not already a string.** It's appended to the url for GET-requests. See
>   processData option to prevent this automatic processing. Object must
>   be Key/Value pairs. **If value is an Array, jQuery serializes multiple
>   values with same key based on the value of the traditional setting**
>   (described below).

*Source: http://api.jquery.com/jquery.ajax/*

Just a note, you can initialize your `array`s literally:

```
var states = [ { Id : 1, Name : 'Maharashtra' }, { Id : 2, Name : 'Punjab' } ],
    Id     = [ 0, 1 ];
```

Answer (score 0):

The JSON string you are creating is invalid JSON. JSON requires double quoting. Start your string with single quotes and use double quotes for keys and values.

Use jsonlint.com to validate